# How to encode a password in Symfony 5?

Tags: php, symfony, password-encryption

I am trying to encode a password in Symfony and after carefully following the documentation [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#c-encoding-passwords) it still seems like I am doing something wrong.

This is my RegisterController.php:

```
<?php
    namespace App\Controller;

    use App\Entity\User;
    use App\Form\Type\UserType;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
    use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
    use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;

class RegisterController extends AbstractController
{
private $passwordEncoder;

public function __construct(UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder)
{
    $this->passwordEncoder = $passwordEncoder;        
}

/**
    * @Route("/register", name="user.register")
    */
public function create(Request $request)
{
    $user = new User();

    $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        $user->setPassword( 
            $this->passwordEncoder->encodePassword( $user, $user->getPassword() )
        );
```

The above returns the following error:

> Neither the property "plainPassword" nor one of the methods "getPlainPassword()", "plainPassword()", "isPlainPassword()", "hasPlainPassword()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class "App\Entity\User".

And here is my Register.twig.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>{% block title %}Register{% endblock %}</title>
        {# {% block stylesheets %}{% endblock %} #}
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Welcome, please register below</h2>
            {{ form(form) }}
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

And finally I have this setup in my `security.yaml` file:

```
security:    
   encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: auto
```

I guess it's something simple that I'm overlooking but I couldn't get it to work. It is my first time with `Symfony`.

Comment: Update your question with a link to the doc your are following.  User::password is used for the final hashed password.  When creating a user, an additional plainPassword property is typically used to store the unhashed password coming from the form.  You probably just need to add plainPassword to your user entity.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually this happen because symfony detect if there is no "plainPassword" property in User entity. The purpose of using this "plainPassword" property is to be a temporary data, so we can encode it. What you need to do is set the "plainPassword" property **mapped to be false** in you form type.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('plainPassword', RepeatedType::class, array(
            'type'              => PasswordType::class,
            'mapped'            => false,
            'first_options'     => array('label' => 'New password'),
            'second_options'    => array('label' => 'Confirm new password'),
            'invalid_message' => 'The password fields must match.',
        ))
    ;
}
```

And in your controller encode the "plainPassword" to be encoded "password":

```
/**
 * @Route("/register", name="app_register")
 */
public function register(Request $request, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder): Response
{
    $user = new User();
    $form = $this->createForm(RegistrationFormType::class, $user);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        // encode the plain password
        $user->setPassword(
            $passwordEncoder->encodePassword(
                $user,
                $form->get('plainPassword')->getData()
            )
        );

        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->persist($user);
        $entityManager->flush();

        // do anything else you need here, like send an email

        return $this->redirectToRoute('any_route');
    }

    return $this->render('registration/register.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is elsewhere.

Check in your twig or in your form if you call the "plainPassword" method, wich doesn't exists, and replace it by "password".

Comment: I have updated my question to include my twig file, which doesn't appear to have `plainPassword` as a method. I am using the helper method `form(form)`

Answer (score 0):

The error seems that is in the twig file. You try to display the `$plainPassword` member, but it is not defined on the entity, most likely (in the begginning of my way to symfony, it happened a lot to have this error). Try to remove it and then check for the error.

As for the encoding of the password, please look at [this url](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#c-encoding-passwords), as it explains how the passwords are encrypted in the security.yml file. You need to define the class that will be encoded, the algorithm can be changed for a custom one, that you can build and for this, please check [this URL](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/named_encoders.html).

The encoding is not so complicated, but the error is not related to the encoding, so please try this and update the post.

Comment: I have updated my question. Yes, I did follow the documentation on the `security.yaml` file. I know the encoding can't be this complicated, maybe I got something wrong on other parts.

Comment: Please add the form content also.

Comment: Whoooshhh I found the error now...referring to `plainPassword` :facepalm. Thanks for your help @fovas

Answer (score 0):

So, I found the error alas! I had set the field `plainPassword` in my UserType.php:

```
class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
        ->add('firstname', TextType::class)
        ->add('lastname', TextType::class)
        ->add('email', EmailType::class)
        ->add('birthdate', DateType::class)
        ->add('plainPassword', RepeatedType::class, array(
            'type' => PasswordType::class,
            'first_options'  => array('label' => 'Password'),
            'second_options' => array('label' => 'Repeat Password'),
        ))
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'Register']);
    }
...
```

Changing this to `password` like I have in my `User` entity corrects the error.

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As of Symfony 5.3 UserPasswordEncoderInterface has been deprecated in favor of UserPasswordHasherInterface. See this article for more information. [Symfony 6 fixtures UserPasswordHasherInterface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70951875/symfony-6-fixtures-userpasswordhasherinterface)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to manually encode password, use cli command:

```
/bin/console security:encode-password
```

For symfony >= 6.0

```
/bin/console security:hash-password
```