# Symfony 6 fixtures UserPasswordHasherInterface

Tags: php, symfony

How can we use UserPasswordHasherInterface  in a fixture to create users in Symfony 6?

```
//App/DataFixtures/AppFixtures.php

namespace App\DataFixtures;

use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Fixture;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Symfony\Component\PasswordHasher\Hasher\UserPasswordHasherInterface;

class AppFixtures extends Fixture
{
    private $manager;

    public function load(ObjectManager $manager, UserPasswordHasherInterface $userPasswordHasherInterface): void
    {
        $this->manager = $manager;

        $user = new User();
        $user->setEmail("test@example.com");
        //$user->setPassword("test_pass");
        $user->setPassword(
            $userPasswordHasherInterface->hashPassword(
                $user, "test_pass"
            )
        );

        $user->setFirstName("Fixture First 1");
        $user->setLastName("Fixture Last 1");

        $this->manager->persist($user);
        $this->manager->flush();
    }
}
```

Error returned

```
Fatal error: Declaration of App\DataFixtures\AppFixtures::load(Doctrine\Persistence\ObjectManager $manager, Symfony\Component\PasswordHasher\Hasher\UserPasswordHasherInterface $userPasswordH
asherInterface): void must be compatible with Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\FixtureInterface::load(Doctrine\Persistence\ObjectManager $manager) in C:\wamp64\www\example.com\src\DataFixtures
\AppFixtures.php on line 14
Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError {#138
  #message: "Compile Error: Declaration of App\DataFixtures\AppFixtures::load(Doctrine\Persistence\ObjectManager $manager, Symfony\Component\PasswordHasher\Hasher\UserPasswordHasherInterface
 $userPasswordHasherInterface): void must be compatible with Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\FixtureInterface::load(Doctrine\Persistence\ObjectManager $manager)"
  #code: 0
  #file: "C:\wamp64\www\example.com\src\DataFixtures\AppFixtures.php"
  #line: 14
  -error: array:4 [
    "type" => 64
    "message" => "Declaration of App\DataFixtures\AppFixtures::load(Doctrine\Persistence\ObjectManager $manager, Symfony\Component\PasswordHasher\Hasher\UserPasswordHasherInterface $userPass
wordHasherInterface): void must be compatible with Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\FixtureInterface::load(Doctrine\Persistence\ObjectManager $manager)"
    "file" => "C:\wamp64\www\example.com\src\DataFixtures\AppFixtures.php"
    "line" => 14
  ]
}
```

Comment: It's a bit unfortunate that there is no "I don't understand the question therefore I'm voting to close it" option.  Random duplicates are are often chosen instead.  This one was particularly sad in that the answers linked were both 10+ years old and, as you say, not very applicable.  On the other hand, you should probably have realized that fixture are not like controller action methods.  You can't just add args.  Additional dependencies are usually injected into the constructor.  So the question itself is not really of much value.

Comment: I haven't used fixtures before,so I was copying examples, most of which were outdated and didn't have a constructor, so overlooked it. Maybe I should rename the question to be about injecting services for anyone else coming here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to inject `UserPasswordHasherInterface` in a `constructor`, like this :

```
//App/DataFixtures/AppFixtures.php

namespace App\DataFixtures;

use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Fixture;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Symfony\Component\PasswordHasher\Hasher\UserPasswordHasherInterface;

class AppFixtures extends Fixture
{
    private $userPasswordHasherInterface;

    public function __construct (UserPasswordHasherInterface $userPasswordHasherInterface) 
    {
        $this->userPasswordHasherInterface = $userPasswordHasherInterface;
    }

    public function load(ObjectManager $manager): void
    {
        $user = new User();
        $user->setEmail("test@example.com");
        //$user->setPassword("test_pass");
        $user->setPassword(
            $this->userPasswordHasherInterface->hashPassword(
                $user, "test_pass"
            )
        );

        $user->setFirstName("Fixture First 1");
        $user->setLastName("Fixture Last 1");

        $manager->persist($user);
        $manager->flush();
    }
}
```